# Change base in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a number and this number's base is 32. I need to convert base to 10. How can I do this with javascript ?

```
var testip="17b3uvp";
var  donus=testip.toString(10);
alert(donus)
```

It is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `parseInt` telling it to use base 32, and then `toString`:

```js
var testip = "17b3uvp";
var parsed = parseInt(testip, 32);
var donus = parsed.toString(); // 10 is the default, but you can specify it for emphasis/clarity if desired
alert(donus);
```

The reason your code wasn't working is that you never converted the string to a number. Calling `toString` on a string just gives you back that string (and `String`'s `toString` doesn't take any arguments). So first we get a number, parsing the string in the right number base, and then we use `Number`'s `toString` to create a string in decimal (`Number`'s `toString` *does* accept a number base, but 10 is the default).

Answer (score 0):

For base conversion in Javascript using parseInt, use the below format

```
parseInt(string,base)
```

`base` can be any number between 2 and 32.

In your case

```
var testip="17b3uvp";
var donus=parseInt(testip,10);
alert(donus)
```

This will alert 17 as result.